# Filter an ArrayList of Objects using Java Streams to return an ArrayList of type String

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

I can't find an exact solution for this on SO. I have a `Crowd` class which consists of a `Crowd` object which is an arraylist of type `People`. `People` is a class with properties `String name, Double bankBalance, Integer numberOfCarsOwned`.

In my crowd class I have the following method whereby I seek to filter by names beginning with the letter P and return these an arraylist of type `String`:

```
  public ArrayList<String> filterByLetterP(){
       ArrayList<String> filteredNames =  this.crowd.stream()
               .filter(name -> name.getName().contains("P"));
               return filteredNames;
    }
```

My error is:
required type `ArrayList<String>` provided `Stream<People>`

**Note: My solution must make use of streams.** How can I correct my solution to get it to work?

### Reference info below.

`People` class definition:

```
public class People {

    private String name;
    private Double bankBalance;
    private Integer numberOfCarsOwned;

    public People(String name, Double bankBalance, Integer numberOfCarsOwned) {
        this.name = name;
        this.bankBalance = bankBalance;
        this.numberOfCarsOwned = numberOfCarsOwned;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Double getBankBalance() {
        return bankBalance;
    }

    public void setBankBalance(Double bankBalance) {
        this.bankBalance = bankBalance;
    }

    public Integer getNumberOfCarsOwned() {
        return numberOfCarsOwned;
    }

    public void setNumberOfCarsOwned(Integer numberOfCarsOwned) {
        this.numberOfCarsOwned = numberOfCarsOwned;
    }
}
```

`Crowd`class definition:

```
public class Crowd {

    private ArrayList<People> crowd;

    public Crowd() {
        this.crowd = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public ArrayList<People> getCrowd() {
        return crowd;
    }

    public void setCrowd(ArrayList<People> crowd) {
        this.crowd = crowd;
    }

    public void addPeopleToCrowd(People people){
        this.crowd.add(people);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> filterByLetterP(){
       ArrayList<String> filteredNames =  this.crowd.stream()
               .filter(name -> name.getName().contains("P"));
               return filteredNames;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things needs to be addressed:

1. You should use `String#startsWith` instead of `String#contains`.
2. You have to map the `Stream` to `People#name`.
3. You have missed collecting the `Stream`.

Do it as shown below:

```
public List<String> filterByLetterP() {
    List<String> filteredNames = this.crowd.stream()
            .map(p -> p.getName())
            .filter(s -> s.startsWith("P"))             
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return filteredNames;
}
```

Comment: This will not work because ```Collectors.toList()``` expects the type ```List```. I have checked. Can you please advise? And also explain the requirement for mapping? Thank you.

Comment: @loco - I've changed the returned type to `List<String>`. It will work now.

Comment: Yeah that works. Thanks, i'll accept your answer. Would you still be able to explain the purpose of map in this context and why I can't use an ArrayList if possible?

Comment: Much better will be to use `map()` first and later check starting with `P` letter: `return this.crowd.stream().map(People::getName).filter(name -> name.startsWith("P")).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: [`Stream#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) is an intermediate operation which returns a value by applying the given function to the elements of this stream.

Comment: [`Collectors#toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) returns a `List`.

Comment: I recommend these tutorials for better understanding: 1. [Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams, Part 1](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html) 2. [Part 2: Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html)

Comment: @catch23 - Thank you. I thought to do that but then started collecting reference materials for the OP and forgot to update the code. I've done it now.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your filter because it doesn't check names with beginning letter 'P':

```
public List<String> filterByLetterP(){
    return this.crowd.stream()
            .map(People::getName)
            .filter(name -> name.charAt(0) == 'P')
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Your solution will not allow me to use the ```.charAt``` method - presumably incorrect type? Also ```Person``` is not a class, my class is ```People``` so I believe you may have a typo? Thanks.

Comment: You're right. Firstly, I should have used map, then filter the names. It should be People, not Person. Sorry for the typo!